# Perform counting for lookup in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to perform lookup based on the number of Yes in Input.

In ID No.1, Output1 is A because it is first Yes, Output2 is B because it is second Yes.
In ID No.2, Output1 is blank because Input1 is n/a, subsequent output is based on number of Yes appeared.
In ID No.3, it shows counting is skipped when the Input2 is not Yes. (so Output3 is H)

Are there any way to do the recursive counting? (Or the only way to find Output3 is to list all 4 possible scenarios? (blank, from Col1, from Col2 and from Col3?)

I would be grateful if I can a way to do it recursively because I have more than 10 input columns.

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Input1 Input2 Input3 Output1 Output2 Output3
1  A    B    C    Yes    Yes    No     A       B       (null)
2  D    E    F    n/a    Yes    Yes    (null)  D       E
3  G    H    I    Yes    No     Yes    G       (null)  H
```

Comment: What happens after we hit the letter `Z`?  Does it wrap around to `AA`, or does something else happen?

Comment: The output is from Col1 / Col2 / Col3 / null, based on number of occurrence of Yes. (i.e. There is no Z or AA.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement to calculate output as following:

```
Select id, 
Col1,
Col2,
Col3,
Input1,
Input2,
Input3,
Case when input1= 'Yes' then col1 end as output1,
Case when input2= 'Yes' then col2 end as output2,
Case when input3= 'Yes' then col3 end as output3
From your_table
```

**-- Update --**

Try this version where I have used `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `CASE` statement as follows:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3,
    INPUT1,
    INPUT2,
    INPUT3,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(OUTPUT, '[^,]', 1, 1) AS OUTPUT1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(OUTPUT, '[^,]', 1, 2) AS OUTPUT2,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(OUTPUT, '[^,]', 1, 3) AS OUTPUT3
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            COL1,
            COL2,
            COL3,
            INPUT1,
            INPUT2,
            INPUT3,
            CASE
                WHEN INPUT1 = 'Yes'  THEN COL1 || ','
            END
            || CASE
                WHEN INPUT2 = 'Yes'  THEN COL2 || ','
            END
            || CASE
                WHEN INPUT3 = 'Yes'  THEN COL3 || ','
            END AS OUTPUT
        FROM
            YOUR_TABLE
    );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This is not correct. In ID2, the Output2 is D, not E (because input1 is not Yes). I know I can use a very long Case statement to do the result. (but any better way? a way to do it reclusive?)

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the requirement. Let me rephrase my answer

Comment: Update: The updated version is correct. It is great because it solved the question recursively.